# I can't figure out why I can't sort and filter divs with jquery

Tags: jquery

After working on my code for quite a while, I finally got everything setup. The CSS is correct, the HTML is correct, and as some of you pointed out, my formatting is correct so I can easily see problems. However, the last step is to be able to sort and filter my divs. As you can see from the code, the whole goal is to keep them together. When I did have it working, it was only pulling specific text and not staying inline. I think I have the inline problem solved, however my jquery is now refusing to respond at all when you start typing in the search bar.

I've tried adding div Id's to all of my  classes, changing the jquery code and a couple other things my frustrated brain can't remember right now.

```
<scriptsrc="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"</script>
<script>
    // <![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function(){
                                      $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
                                        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
                                        $("#myDiv").filter(function() {
                                          $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
                                        });
                                      });
                                    });
    // ]]>
</script>
```

```
    <div class="div1"><input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search.." /></div>
    <div class="gridcontainer">
        <div class="divtablecell">NEW 2018 DODGE JOURNEY V6 VALUE PACKAGE <br /> VIN: 3C4PDCBG1JT508626 STOCK #: 082030 <br /> MSRP$27,385
            <p><a target="_self" href="pid:15311737" class="buttonGhost">Request internet advertised price.</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="divtablecell">NEW 2018 JEEP RENEGADE ALTITUDE 4X2 <br /> VIN: ZACCJABB4JPH91207 STOCK #: 586043 <br /> MSRP$25,915
            <p><a target="_self" href="pid:15311737" class="buttonGhost">Request internet advertised price.</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="divtablecell">NEW 2018 DODGE JOURNEY V6 VALUE PACKAGE <br /> VIN: 3C4PDCBG3JT511401 STOCK #: 082035 <br /> MSRP$27,385
            <p><a target="_self" href="pid:15311737" class="buttonGhost">Request internet advertised price.</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="divtablecell">NEW 2018 JEEP RENEGADE SPORT 4X4 <br /> VIN: ZACCJBAB4JPJ43841 STOCK #: 586049 <br /> MSRP$26,240
            <p><a target="_self" href="pid:15311737" class="buttonGhost">Request internet advertised price.</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="divtablecell">NEW 2018 JEEP RENEGADE SPORT 4X4 <br /> VIN: ZACCJBAB3JPJ42826 STOCK #: 586051 <br /> MSRP$26,240
            <p><a target="_self" href="pid:15311737" class="buttonGhost">Request internet advertised price.</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="divtablecell">NEW 2019 JEEP COMPASS SPORT FWD <br /> VIN: 3C4NJCAB8KT615373 STOCK #: 492005 <br /> MSRP$25,285
            <p><a target="_self" href="pid:15311737" class="buttonGhost">Request internet advertised price.</a></p>
        </div>
```

Comment: Typo: `<scriptsrc` should be `<script src`.

Comment: NB: don't use `.filter()` for just iterating. Use `.each()` instead.

Comment: Try changing `#myDiv` to `.divtablecell`

Comment: The script source typo was when I copied the code thank you for the .filter tip. Also thank you all. I realized when I was using #myDiv and switched it to .divtablecell I was actually using #divtablecell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem 1) there is no element with an id of **mydiv**

Problem 2) `$("#myDiv")` would target a single element with an id of **myDiv**, if it existed.

Solution: change your selector to `$(".divtablecell")` to select all `div` with that class.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(".divtablecell").each(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1"><input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search.." /></div>
<div class="gridcontainer">
  <div class="divtablecell">NEW 2018 DODGE JOURNEY V6 VALUE PACKAGE <br /> VIN: 3C4PDCBG1JT508626 STOCK #: 082030 <br /> MSRP$27,385
    <p><a target="_self" href="pid:15311737" class="buttonGhost">Request internet advertised price.</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="divtablecell">NEW 2018 JEEP RENEGADE ALTITUDE 4X2 <br /> VIN: ZACCJABB4JPH91207 STOCK #: 586043 <br /> MSRP$25,915
    <p><a target="_self" href="pid:15311737" class="buttonGhost">Request internet advertised price.</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="divtablecell">NEW 2018 DODGE JOURNEY V6 VALUE PACKAGE <br /> VIN: 3C4PDCBG3JT511401 STOCK #: 082035 <br /> MSRP$27,385
    <p><a target="_self" href="pid:15311737" class="buttonGhost">Request internet advertised price.</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="divtablecell">NEW 2018 JEEP RENEGADE SPORT 4X4 <br /> VIN: ZACCJBAB4JPJ43841 STOCK #: 586049 <br /> MSRP$26,240
    <p><a target="_self" href="pid:15311737" class="buttonGhost">Request internet advertised price.</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="divtablecell">NEW 2018 JEEP RENEGADE SPORT 4X4 <br /> VIN: ZACCJBAB3JPJ42826 STOCK #: 586051 <br /> MSRP$26,240
    <p><a target="_self" href="pid:15311737" class="buttonGhost">Request internet advertised price.</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="divtablecell">NEW 2019 JEEP COMPASS SPORT FWD <br /> VIN: 3C4NJCAB8KT615373 STOCK #: 492005 <br /> MSRP$25,285
    <p><a target="_self" href="pid:15311737" class="buttonGhost">Request internet advertised price.</a></p>
  </div>
```